# Get number of rows updated ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, execute

I use ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction to execute a stored procedure which insert data to a table.

The ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction always return -1 even the records are inserted to db. Why it always returns a -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your stored procedure contains `SET NOCOUNT ON`. If so remove it.